# URI Relative Resource in Silverlight

Tags: c#, file, silverlight, uri, relative-path

I have a file within my Silverlight project, within a folder.

My project is called Display

Solution Explorer structure:

```
/Resources
    cube.obj
```

My code is:

```
Uri u = new Uri(@"Display;component/Resources/cube.obj", UriKind.Relative);
Stream stream = Application.GetResourceStream(u).Stream;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

cube.obj has the build action set to Content if that's relevant.

I'm getting a NullReferenceException that comes up in the JavaScript and doesn't give me much help in determining the issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the file's build action to "Resource", not "Content".

The `NullReferenceException` is coming from the `Application.GetResourceStream(u).Stream`.  `GetResourceStream` returns `null` because the file isn't available because it's the wrong build action. Accessing `Stream` on the null reference then fires the exception.

EDIT: Also make sure that your Uri "Display;" portion is the proper name for your assembly that is housing the obj file.

Just to clarify.  Use `Content` when you want the file to be placed in the XAP file alongside the various assemblies.  You can then access the file without the prefix "Display;component" path. (NOTE: off the top of my head, I don't think I've loaded a "Content" resource in this way with `Application.GetResourceStream` specifically so I don't know for sure if it will work, but I suspect it would).  I also suspect this could cause issues if you have the same file name located in different paths/projects. This method is especially useful if you want to share the same resource/file with multiple projects/assemblies.

Using `Resource` will keep the file embedded *within* the assembly DLL.  With this, you need to specify the assembly to look in (hence the "Display;component" prefix).  But this is necessary if you're packaging pre-compiled assemblies for use in your Silverlight project or want to manage the files differently.

Comment: I get a different error now, Format_InvalidString. I'm guessing this is what you're referring to. How do I determine the assembly that is housing the obj file?

Comment: @pcaston2 it should be the compiled assembly file name without the ".dll" extension.  So if your compiled project/assembly file name is "MyProject.View.dll" then you would use "MyProject.View;component"

Comment: Actually, `GetResourceStream` doesn't throw an invalid string format exception; only ArgumentException and ArgumentNullException. The `Uri` constructor can throw a `UriFormatException` which _possibly_ is what you're seeing thought I would have expected you to get that first.  Is it possible that you're now have a valid stream to the file and it's your subsequent code reading the file that's failing?

Comment: I have multiple projects within my solution. I checked within the Display project (my Silverlight web app) and it contains a Display.dll, I couldn't find any other DLLs other than Microsoft references. So as I said the corresponding string 'Display;component/Resources/cube.obj' gives me an error.

Comment: Yes I was just going to try that, it looks like the block I had an issue with is resolved, this error is coming from other code which I've commented out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling Silverlight debugging on your project, that way you'll be able to step through the SL code, Go to your project properties then on Debug go all the way down and enable the Silverlight debugger, then run your project and your SL breakpoints will be hit.

Comment: The project I'm working on was originally an MVC3 app, I tacked on a Silverlight app and tried for awhile in the past to get the debug feature to work, while using Chrome. I haven't been able to get that functionality to work unfortunately.

Comment: @pcaston2 AFAIK, Silverlight debugging only works in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I may be wrong but I've heard people having success with Chrome. My VS 2010 says the symbols weren't loaded (must be a configuration problem in my project) and I've tried IE with similar issues. Followed a few tutorials but never got it to work, pretty sure I know where the issue is in the code, just not sure what to do about it.